# Asociar un evento doble click en un QTableWidget a un slot y obtener la fila

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget

Estoy tratando que al hacer doble click sobre la fila de una tabla me haga la llamada al método y saber qué fila es. He probado a hacer:

```
def Tabla(self):
    #Boton de exportar a excel
    toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
    icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd()+"\\images\\excel_tras.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

    toolButton.setIcon(icon1)
    toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
    #toolButton.clicked.connect(lambda i: exportar(self))

    #Tabla
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    table.setObjectName("table")

    tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.columnas))
    tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.listaDatos))
    tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
    #Definir los eventos de la tabla
    tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

    #Evento
    tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(lambda i: on_click(i, self)) 

    #Colocamos la cabecera
    tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columnas)
    header_view = tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
    header_view.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    #Layout
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(tableWidget, 7, 0, 5, 7)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(toolButton, 6, 5, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    return tableWidget

#Metodo asociado al evento de hacer doble click sobre una fila de la tabla    
def on_click(i, self):
    print(self.sender())#widget
    print(i)#qmodelindex
```

Pero no soy capaz de obtener el índice de la fila que he seleccionado.

Al añadir el slot el código me quedaría como:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import configparser
import os
from util.excelUtil import *


class Tabla(QWidget):
'''
Metodo base para la creación de una tabla con el botón de exportación a excel
'''
def __init__(self, contenidoTabla):
        #Boton de exportar a excel
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd()+"\\images\\excel_tras.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

        self.toolButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(lambda i: exportar(contenidoTabla))

        #Tabla
        contenidoTabla.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        contenidoTabla.table.setObjectName("table")

        contenidoTabla.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(contenidoTabla.columnas))
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(contenidoTabla.listaDatos))
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        #Definir los eventos de la tabla
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        #Evento
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

        #Colocamos la cabecera
        contenidoTabla.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(contenidoTabla.columnas)
        header_view = contenidoTabla.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        header_view.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        #Layout
        contenidoTabla.mainLayout.addWidget(contenidoTabla.tableWidget, 7, 0, 5, 7)
        contenidoTabla.mainLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 6, 5, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

#Metodo asociado al evento de hacer doble click sobre una fila de la tabla    
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem)
def on_click(self, item):
    print(item.text())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La señal `doubleClick` ya retorna una instancia [`QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) de la cual puedes obtener sin problemas el índice de la fila con `QModelIndex.row()`, el problema es que la firma de tus `slots` y su llamada son incorrectos en principio. Un método de instancia siempre tiene que recibir `self` **como primer argumento**, además **`self` es pasado de forma automática**, no debes pasarlo tu explícitamente al llamar.

Por otro lado, al llamar a un método definido `def metodo(self, arg1)` debes hacerlo mediante `self.metodo(arg1)`, no mediante `metodo(self, arg1)` (en todo caso sería `NombreDeLaClase.metodo(self, arg1)` que es lo que hace realmente `self.metodo(arg1)`)

Conecta la señal con:

```
tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)
```

Tu slot puede quedar así:

```
# from PyQt5 import QtCore

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
def on_click(self, index):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()
    print(row, column)
```

Con el botón pasa igual, no uses `lambda` para intentar pasar la instancia de la clase, simplemente:

```
toolButton.clicked.connect(self.exportar)
```

Siempre y cuando `exportar` y `on_click` sean por supuesto métodos de instancia de la misma clase que es el método `Tabla`. Dejo de todas formas un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets 



class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.columnas = ["Columna 1", "Columna 2"]
        self.listaDatos = [["A", "B"],["C", "D"]]  
        self.tabla()        


    def tabla(self):
        #Boton de exportar a excel
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.exportar)   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        #Tabla
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.setObjectName("table")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.columnas))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.listaDatos))

        #Colocamos la cabecera
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columnas)
        header_view = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        idx = header_view.count() - 1
        header_view.setSectionResizeMode(idx, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        #Colocamos los datos
        for fila, lista in enumerate(self.listaDatos):
            for columna, elemento in enumerate(lista):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(fila, columna,
                                         QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(elemento)
                                         )
        # Evento
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        #Layout
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 7, 0, 5, 7)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 6, 5, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)


    #Metodo asociado al evento de hacer doble click sobre una fila de la tabla 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_click(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        print(row, column)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def exportar(self):
        '''
        A modo de ejemplo solo imprime el contenido de la tabla
        en forma de csv
        '''
        print("Exportando tabla:")
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            print(",".join(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text()
                for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount())))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Example()
    dialog.exec_()
```

Dependiendo de que quieras finalmente conseguir hay un par de señales más que te podrían se de ayuda:

- [`itemDoubleClicked(item: QTableWidgetItem)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemDoubleClicked)

  ```
  self.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

  @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem)
  def on_click(self, item):
      print(item.text())
  ```
- [`cellDoubleClicked(row: int, column: int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellDoubleClicked)

  ```
  self.tableWidget.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

  @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
  def on_click(self, row, column):
      print(row, column)
  ```

Para los headers tienes también señales similares, como [`sectionDoubleClicked(logicalIndex: int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionDoubleClicked) para obtener el índice de la fila si se hace doble click en una sección del header vertical:

```
self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().sectionDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_hheader_click)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def on_hheader_click(self, index):
    print(index)
```

Comment: Un ejemplo muy completo, muchas gracias. Ahora bien, he tratado de reproducir el ejemplo sobre mi código pero si le añado el slot me falla: TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with doubleClicked(QModelIndex)

Comment: Hola @Adriana_0_0 edita tu pregunta si quieres y al final de ella, sin elminar lo que hay para que no pierda el contexto, agrega el nuevo código a ver si vemos que está pasando. Si mi ejemplo te funciona correctamente seguramente se te ha escapado algún detalle al trasladarlo a tu código.

Comment: Hola, he añadido todo el código de mi archivo .py por si se trata de alguna importación o alguna otra cosa que le afecte. Gracias!

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 usas la señal incorrecta, si te fijas en las alternativas que coloco más abajo para recibir el item tienes que usar `self.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)`, en tu caso usas `self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)` que pasa `QModelIndex` al slot, por eso se queja ya que la firma no coincide.

Comment: Ok. Lo he cambiado a "itemDoubleClicked" pero me muestra el error: "contenidoTabla.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)" TypeError: connect() failed between itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem*) and on_click()

Comment: Si, no me había dado cuenta... No llamas al `__init__` del padre (`QWidget`) en tu clase `Tabla`, si sobreescribes el método debes llamar siempre al del padre para que la inicialización del widget sea correcta: `def __init__(self, contenidoTabla, *args, **kwargs):`  e inmediatamente debajo `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, luego el resto del contenido de tu `__init__`.